# How to split chunk of text in text file and save it into a object or list?

Tags: python, split

I have this text file containing text like this

> Total Number of Direction(s): 2
>
> 1.) ZRB0002, LA_ATC_ZATC, HECAZATC, 21.08.2021 00:00:55
> 2.) CJC002, LA_NEW_CAPITAL_ZAZR, HECPZAZR, 21.08.2021 00:00:56
>
> FF HECAZATC 210001 OEJNINDA
> (EST-DLH637/A4252-OERK-PASAM/0011F380-EDDF)
>
> Number of Chars: 12 Number of Words: 3
>
> Total Number of Direction(s): 2
>
> 1.) ZRB0002, LA_ATC_ZATC, HECAZATC, 21.08.2021 00:00:55
> 2.) CJC002, LA_NEW_CAPITAL_ZAZR, HECPZAZR, 21.08.2021 00:00:56
>
> FF HECAZATC 210001 OEJNINDA
> (EST-DLH637/A4252-OERK-PASAM/0011F380-EDDF)
>
> Number of Chars: 12 Number of Words: 3

I want to split the whole file with

> Total Number of Direction(s)

and take whatever comes after it as a string and save it into a list or serialized dict.

Desired output:

```
{1 :  "Total Number of Direction(s): 2
1.) ZRB0002, LA_ATC_ZATC, HECAZATC, 21.08.2021 00:00:55 2.) CJC002, LA_NEW_CAPITAL_ZAZR, HECPZAZR, 21.08.2021 00:00:56
FF HECAZATC 210001 OEJNINDA (EST-DLH637/A4252-OERK-PASAM/0011F380-EDDF)
Number of Chars: 12 Number of Words: 3" , 2: "Total Number of Direction(s): 2
1.) ZRB0002, LA_ATC_ZATC, HECAZATC, 21.08.2021 00:00:55 2.) CJC002, LA_NEW_CAPITAL_ZAZR, HECPZAZR, 21.08.2021 00:00:56
FF HECAZATC 210001 OEJNINDA (EST-DLH637/A4252-OERK-PASAM/0011F380-EDDF)
Number of Chars: 12 Number of Words: 3"}
```

I tried the `startswith()` function and I tried to loop over the entire file which is about 76500 lines and then save each line into list and when the item in the list is equal to "Total Number of Direction" merge the index until you find index with value "Total Number of Direction" but it didn't work.

Comment: based on the sample - how should the dict look like?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i tried startswith()  fucntion  ,, i tried also to and make an if condition but I cant save the text under it and then make it stop when it sees another Total Number of Direction

Comment: Unless you are *specifically* asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed both for the time being.

Comment: @balderman did solve it thanks to him and thank you too tripleee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below - it should work

```
counter = 0
data = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Total Number of Direction(s)'):
            counter += 1
            data[counter] = line
        else:
            data[counter] += line
for k, v in data.items():
    print(f'{k} --> {v}')
```

Comment: Thank you so much balderman  the else part was my stop point،

Comment: This doesn't quite work because the line beginning "Total Number...' won't be included in the dictionary value(s)

Comment: @DarkKnight - see the requested output.

Comment: I did check it and it needs to include "Total Number of Directions". It's in the Desired Output section of the question